# Possibility of transferring power to train through rails

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, transportation, infrastructure

(I'm designing setting where technology is modern like, but quite a few technologies are simply different)

I know that train can be powered through overhead wire or third rail.

For practical purposes the third rail looks good as starting point. Direct current from the third rail and later returns through rails. OK so the question is - **Would it be possible to get rid of the third rail, and just use one rail as minus, another as plus and in the result power the train without neither overhead wires nor third rail?**

Technically speaking such rails are already a thick piece of steel, so look quite good as conductor. I assume that it would have to be well isolated from the ground. I also assume that it would have some system like in ground level power supply to energise only relevant rail segment with the train to avoid electrocuting anyone who touched rails.

Would such system be realistic and practical enough to be used?

Comment: I think this is a poor question because it's answered directly on Wikipedia.  That is, “no prior research”.

Comment: I doubt if this qualifies as world building. It's a question about existing technology, with little to no explanation how this tech would change the world, and hardly any room for fiction.

Answer (score 6):

Getting rid of third rail is possible, but impractical:

[Running_rails_for_power_supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_rail#Running_rails_for_power_supply)

> The first idea for feeding electricity to a train from an external
>   source was by using both rails on which a train runs, whereby each
>   rail is a conductor for each polarity, and is insulated by the
>   sleepers. This method is used by most scale model trains, however it
>   does not work so well for large trains as the sleepers are not good
>   insulators, furthermore the use of insulated wheels or insulated axles
>   is required. As most insulation materials have poor mechanical
>   properties compared with metals used for this purpose, this results in
>   a less stable train vehicle. Nevertheless, it was sometimes used at
>   the beginning of the development of electric trains. The oldest
>   electric railway in the world, the Volk's Railway in Brighton, England
>   was originally electrified at 50 volts DC using this system (it is now
>   a three rail system). Other railway systems that used it were the
>   Gross-Lichterfelde Tramway and the Ungerer Tramway.

Answer (score 2):

Model trains get their power from the tracks without a third rail. The method was attempted for real trains in the early days of subways but did not scale up. Quoting from Wikipedia article about third rails:

> The first idea for feeding electricity to a train from an external source was by using both rails on which a train runs, whereby each rail is a conductor for each polarity, and is insulated by the sleepers. This method is used by most scale model trains, however it does not work so well for large trains as the sleepers are not good insulators, furthermore the use of insulated wheels or insulated axles is required. As most insulation materials have poor mechanical properties compared with metals used for this purpose, this results in a less stable train vehicle.

--- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_rail

Comment: Lol, dueling quotations. If only you had quoted more than Alexander, you might have the +4.

Answer (score -1):

Another problem is that steel is strong enough to support the weight of a train repeatedly moving over the rails. Steel is not a good conductor of electricity. So this method will be inefficient in delivering power.

While all metals are conductive, we use aluminum, copper, silver, and gold for conductors. These metals are all soft, and expensive. Even if you use steel rails and plate them the plating will become thinner and thinner with each passing train. Gaps will appear in the plating and it will be ineffective. Gold, silver, (maybe copper) plating will also be subject to thieves.

Also consider thermal expansion. Track in the sun will heat and expand in the day, cool and shrink at night. Summer-winter temperatures will increase the range in temperatures. Over a year, the track must have room for this expansion, otherwise the track will warp, buckle, and pull off the sleepers. Iron has a lower thermal expansion than the conductive metals http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/linear-expansion-coefficients-d_95.html.

New technology: could one make a doped carbon fiber rail that would be strong enough to take the physical pounding while being sufficiently conductive to make power transmission feasible? Maybe a new ceramic material. Ceramic would have the durability, but might be too brittle. You might help by limiting rail to passenger traffic rather than cargo.

MolbOrg made some good comments that should be addressed.
The third rail is made of steel (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_rail). However, this choice has consequences. Third rail systems use lower voltage DC current. This is due to safety and the conductivity of steel. This limits train speed. This also means that power substations need to be fairly close together. Wikipedia also mentioned a mechanical limitation to making contact with the third rail, but I was not clear exactly what this involved. There is a possibility of using aluminum rails with a stainless steel facing to improve durability. Wikipedia did not provide a working example.

The Wikipedia article discussing overhead lines provides important contrast for a system not limited by worker safety, or problems with leaves/ trash/ snow that could interfere with power transmission (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_line).

In developing a new system there are several things to consider. AC versus DC. DC is more lethal, but the entire wire carries current. AC can be safer, but it travels only skin deep (based on frequency). Conductivity of the material used to make the rails. Mechanical durability, chemical durability (rust), and thermal expansion will be important. Finally there is cost: cost of the materials, cost of fabrication, cost of power stations.

Comment: Rail are used to conducting electricity for the trains today when being made from steel. At subways, at railroads, at city trains.

Comment: Ah, so the electric companies are simply stupid for using expensive copper. They should use steel cable because it is less expensive and stronger.

Comment: It will be not less expensive, but they may. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/rstiv.html - iron resistance/copper resistance = 5.77976190476, thus a steel cable about 2.7 times thicker than copper cable will have the same resistance/conductivity/heat losses. Hm, but in the case, it will be indeed cheaper, tonne of steel have cost about \$300-325 per tonne, copper \$5800 per tonne, so about 3 times cheaper to use steel in the case than copper.

Comment: the bottom part of page 27 https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7164/e18003096f8f2c4239c3dbef318342c02c09.pdf . IDK try to read that wiki article pretty interesting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_electrification_system , it is not easy for me to find a description in english language where they directly say yes we use rails. Still it is open information, and can be found in the literature about making rails roads, so you may take trip to a library and try to find the book.